# Does Rails engines support i18n

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, i18n-gem, rails-i18n

What I am trying to do is have a translation file in my engine. I have placed files in

> config
>
> ```
>  \locales
>
>      \fr.yml
> ```

Now I am writing translation for string hello

fr:
  "Hello":"Bonjour"
but I am getting translation error. When I use same line in my application translate file it works.

I just want to know whether translation files in engines work or not? If yes can you tell the error I am doing.

Thanks

Comment: Can you paste the error you're getting? Translations should definitely work in engines.

Comment: Hey igot the soln, you should add i18n in gem file of you engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally i found it,use gem i18n in the engine.

Thanks

Comment: I have the same problem..but adding I18n to my engine does not work.. anyone an idea what could be an other solution?